# Running exported databricks notebook in a local spark on a vm

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have installed spark locally with its all dependencies on a vm.

[image]

Now I want to run an exported databricks notebook in this environment. Can I achieve this aim without using jupyter?

Comment: Which kind of notebook are you trying to run? Is there any visualization or command that makes sense only in Databricks (e.g., `display`)?

Comment: There are no visualization or anything special related to Databricks.

Answer (score 1):

You can export a Databricks notebook as a "plain" python file (`File > Export` menu) containing the code from all the cells.

Databricks use comments in this file to reconstruct the notebook structure if you reimport it, but, being comments, they are skipped by the Python interpreter if you run the file as a script locally.

The only thing missing is a spark session (`spark` variable in the notebook code). You can add the following lines at the beginning of this file in order to have a `spark` instance:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

and then use `spark-submit` in your local environment:

```bash
spark-submit your_notebook.py
```

Mind that this approach works only for very simple notebooks, without anything that is specific to Databricks functionalities or utils.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This way but doesnt work for`.ipynb` files. correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. Anyway, do you need to run the `.ipynb` file or you can run the correspondent source file (w.r.t. the Databricks notebook) instead?

Comment: I need to run `.ipynb` files in payspark console on my VM

Comment: Excuse me, to clarify: `.ipynb` files are exports of Databricks notebooks?

Comment: yes, they are exported from databricks

Comment: So you can export directly as Python scripts (`.py`) instead of Jupyter notebooks (`.ipynb`); alternatively, you can  convert `.ipynb` files to `.py` using `nbconvert`(https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#convert-script).